# Python list index not in order

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to make it so that my text alternates between upper and lower case like the question ask. It seems to skip 3 in the indexing and I can't figure out why.

```
sentence = input("Write a sentence")

newList = []
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[i] != " ":
        newList.append(sentence[i])


listJoint = "".join(newList)
newList2 = []

for i in range(len(listJoint)):
    if (listJoint.index(listJoint[i]) % 2) == 0:
        print(listJoint.index(listJoint[i]))
        newList2.append(listJoint[i].upper())
    elif (listJoint.index(listJoint[i]) % 2) != 0:
        print(listJoint.index(listJoint[i]))
        newList2.append(listJoint[i].lower())

print(newList2)

#newListJoint = "".join(newList2)
#print(newListJoint[::-1])
```

Thanks in advance
[List index doesn't go 0 1 2 3 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ1Vx.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: seeing code as image makes it harder to copy paste and also to test

Comment: `index` is very much the wrong tool for this job.  Remember, `index` returns the FIRST occurrence of the character.   If you have three Ls, it will return the same one each time.  You need to have your loop go by indexes.

Comment: Consider to use *List Comp* like this - ```ans = [ch.upper() if not idx%2 else ch.lower() for idx, ch in enumerate(word)]```

Answer (score 1):

The function .index() finds the first occurrence of that letter. 'L' occurs at index 2 and 3 so it would return 2 for both L's.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each character of the string and alternate upper/lower methods.

```
sentence = "Hello"

alternated_sentence = ''
for i, char in enumerate(sentence):
    if i % 2:
        alternated_sentence += char.upper()
    else:
        alternated_sentence += char.lower()

print(alternated_sentence)
#hElLo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = input("Write a sentence:")
# Remove spaces (as per your question)
sentence = sentence.replace(' ', '')
# Reverse the string order (as per your question)
sentence = sentence[::-1]

result = []
for i in range(len(sentence)):
  if(i%2==1):
    result.append(sentence[i].lower())
  else:
    result.append(sentence[i].upper())

print(''.join(result))
```

Here's the solution. The above code would give output as follows:

```
Write a sentence: Hello world
DlRoWoLlEh
```

Answer (score 0):

I never realised index method referenced the first instance of the character. This works:

```
sentence = input("Write a sentence")

newList = []
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[i] != " ":
        newList.append(sentence[i])


listJoint = "".join(newList)
newList2 = []


for i, value in enumerate(newList):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        newList2.append(listJoint[i].upper())
    elif i % 2 !=0:
        newList2.append(listJoint[i].lower())

newListJoint = "".join(newList2)
print(newListJoint[::-1])
```